# Removing Nonce from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce

I want to remove default nonces from default wordpress profile update page (*wordpress/wp-admin/profile.php*). I'm trying to make CSRF with wordpress password change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove default nonce from default admin profile update page. Please check `wp-admin/profile.php` which actually inherits `wp-admin/user-edit.php`. Here you'll see that the nonce fields are hard coded like at ***line 220*** at `user-edit.php` file you'll get `<?php wp_nonce_field('update-user_' . $user_id) ?>` and there is no way to manipulate that without editing the file `user-edit.php`. And editing this core file is strictly prohibited in ***WordPress*** convention. So in a nutshell you can't remove the default nonce from default admin page.